# How to get Object Oriented Programming Concepts?

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

What is the best way or best resources or tutorials to learn Object Oriented Programming?

For instance, when I begin a program with Java and all my code goes into just one class and I can't estimate when I need to create new classes and operate on these classes together.

Comment: yes you can break the one class in many classes according to requirment and functionality  so when other  one try to understand  he will go to that class only   so its easier  for problum solving and also   less buggy code easiy to find the error .

Comment: I got the concepts academically at school, but it took exposure to real-world projects to actually "get it".

Comment: Your question is too broad. How does one "learn" anything? There are thousands of books and online resources and projects for you to learn OOP. Just pick a couple that a friend or colleague recommends, and go from there.

Comment: Try getting a copy of __Head First Design Patterns__ (http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1379530325&sr=1-1&keywords=head+first+design+patterns)

Answer (score 3):

**A class must aim to do one thing and do it well. Nothing else.**

There's more to it than that, but that's the main thing. If you go by that you can't go wrong.
If your class does too much, it's time to break it apart into smaller pieces.

This is known as the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>:

> In object-oriented programming, the **single responsibility principle** states that every class should have a **single responsibility**, and that responsibility should be **entirely encapsulated** by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

---

Note that I am just answering your example. For the rest, your question is too broad. Your best bet to "get" OOP will be to indeed practice OOP. Just:

1. Read a few books.
2. Do some projects to break your teeth on these concepts a few times.
3. Don't try to memorize all these fancy names (including the SRP above).
4. Get your code [bashed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/teamwork-and-working-alone-for-too-long) and [reviewed](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I agree. I know learning and understanding the SOLID principles helped me quite a bit. And this *is* the first of them.
Here are the rest. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Answer (score 0):

It starts at the design phase, before you write any code.  Think about what your program is modelling.  If its an e-commerce website you might think about Customer, order, product and so on.  These nouns become your first objects.

Then you think about what processes need to occur. As an example, when the website takes a new order, there will need to be a point where you take payment for the order.  You may define an object as Payment, and this object represents the payment details, and the status of the payment. Now different payment types need processing differently. So you could define a common interface IPaymentProcessor and then create payment processor objects that each only process particular types of payment. e.g PayPalPaymentProcessor and VisaPaymentProcessor.

At this stage, you are starting to write object oriented code...

Comment: And a IPaymentProcessorFactory.

Comment: @anakata And an IPaymentProcessorFactoryAdapterFacadeVisitorTemplateMethod. It's not Java otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to the [Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.ar/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)! :P

Comment: Don't forget IPaymentProcessorFactoryAdapterFacadeVisitorTemplateMethodImpl, because being Java I hope IPaymentProcessorFactoryAdapterFacadeVisitorTemplateMethod to be an abstract interface.

Answer (score 0):

The Sun/Oracle API, particularly the Javadoc but also the source code itself, provides lots of good examples.  You'll use this stuff anyway; when you do, just take a harder look at it than you need to do to get the job done.  In particular, JTable is very interesting.  It and its associated classes have way too many methods, which muddles it a bit as a learning tool.  (I'm becoming convinced that convenience methods are evil.)  But note particularly how it uses TableModel.  (And also rows, row selection, columns, printing a cell, editing a cell....)

It can take a while to grasp what Sun was doing.  OOP tends to be at right angles to everything else; you have to get your brain to think in different ways and then *keep* it thinking differently.

To try to put OO into two sentences:  An object acts as a server, returning information or taking an action upon request.  In doing this it can also act as a client and use other servers to do things or return information.  (And it *can* treat, upon request, a client as a server and feed back information on its own schedule and initiative.)

Comment: "OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and hiding of state-process, and extreme late-binding of all things. It can be done in Smalltalk and in LISP. There are possibly other systems in which this is possible, but I’m not aware of them." Alan Kay